# argument src is required node azure

Tags: azure, express

I am trying to deploy an Express app to Azure. I am able to deploy the app to Azure but as soon as I try to run it I get the following error. It doesn't happen on my dev machine not too sure what is going on -

Mon Jan 22 2018 22:06:53 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: argument src is required
    at merge (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\merge-descriptors\index.js:37:11)
    at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:50:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\index.js:2:18)

Any ideas would be appreciated.